# How to animate only one icon in *ngFor angular?

Tags: css, angular

```
<div class="text-content" *ngFor="let user of items | async">
<div class="user">
   <span>user</span>
  <p>{{user.some}}</p>
  <div class="comment-line"></div>
  <div class="comment">
    <i  *ngIf="user.hasOwnProperty(uid)" class="material-icons"  id="favorite" (click)="dislike(user.key, uid)">favorite</i>
    <i  *ngIf="!user.hasOwnProperty(uid)"  class="material-icons"  id="favorite_border" (click)="like(user.key, uid)">favorite_border</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to animate only one icon with CSS transition, only one not all the rest icon. Any solution?

Comment: Which is that one first, last, number? `favorite`, `favorite_border`? You should share your code what you have tried/

Comment: I have a forum-like app, each post has an emotion smilie, I want each post smile to do the animation independently.

Comment: Simply add `visibleUser: User = null;` to the component.  Add `[class.selected]="visibleUser === user"` to the element that needs to be rotated. Add `(click)="visibleUser = user"` to the div with the `NgForDirective`. Style the `.selected` with a transition